# Is there a command in ActiveSync thats's similar to Append/Store in IMAP?

Tags: email, activesync

Just started looking at ActiveSync protocol, so I am not too familiar with it.  What I want to do is to add an email to a folder with specified date and flags.  In IMAP, I can do that with APPEND, but I can't seem to find something similar in ActiveSync.

Is something like that possible with ActiveSync?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible with EAS, but you might want to look at Exchange Web Services (EWS) instead. Otherwise you'll end up implementing a boat load of foundational stuff before you get to even get to put something into an email folder.

Comment: I am trying to do this for outlook.com, and EWS isn't supported on outlook.com. :(

Comment: EWS is supported in Outlook.com / Office365: http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/148/p/57006/206833.aspx#206833

Comment: Hmm... according to this post, it isn't... http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/mail-profile/i-want-to-access-outlookcom-account-over-exchange/83971a95-7fb3-483a-96fc-ac7e0299345b?msgId=71d12357-f735-4958-baef-39997b5802c8 I guess I'll test it out and see.  Thanks.

Comment: Try it, it does work. I've done it myself.